# chained list - overwritten data

Tags: c++, list, chained

I coded this easy chained list in C++. But there is a strange problem which let
's me confused. In my program the user should be able to enter as many names and ages as they like, and they should all get chained with each other.
But however, if i enter A and 1, B and 2, C and 3 and then D and 4, then `C and 3` is getting overwritten with `D and 4`. Can someone explain why this is the case?

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct T_Schueler
{
    string Name;
    string Age;
    T_Schueler *pnext;
};

T_Schueler *pStart = NULL;

int main()
{
    string name, age;

    while(true)
    {
        system("cls");

        cout<<"Please enter name: "; 
        cin>>   name;

        cout<<"Please enter age: "; 
        cin>>   age;

        T_Schueler      *pAllok, *pRun, *pLoesch;
        pAllok          =   new(T_Schueler);
        pAllok->pnext   =   NULL;

        cout<<"\n\nNew dataset created.\n\n";

        if(pStart == NULL)
        {
            pStart          =   pAllok;
            pStart->Name    =   name;
            pStart->Age =   age;
        }
        else
        {
            pRun            =   pStart;

            if (pRun->pnext !=  NULL)
            {
                pRun        =   pRun->pnext;
            }

            pRun->pnext =   pAllok;
            pRun            =   pRun->pnext;
            pRun->Name      =   name;
            pRun->Age   =   age;
        }

//OUtput

        pRun    =   pStart;

        cout<<"Names: "<<endl;

        while(pRun  !=  NULL)
        {
            cout<<  pRun->Name  <<  " -> ";
            pRun    =   pRun->pnext;
        }

        pRun = pStart;

        cout<<"\nAges: "<<endl;

        while(pRun  !=  NULL)
        {
            cout<<  pRun->Age   <<  " -> ";
            pRun    =   pRun->pnext;
        }

        cout<<endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }


    cin.get();cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are looking for the end of the linked list

```
if (pRun->pnext !=  NULL)
{
    pRun        =   pRun->pnext;
}
```

you want to use a `while` instead of an `if` to handle the case of several nodes already in the list.

You already do that when printing, but not when inserting.